# RSS reader in windows phone app studio

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, rss

I am trying to useu RSS reader element in WP App Studio i was able to read the contents of any RSS link and display them on the WP app page, i have been trying to do so again with this link

http://www.jopharma.com/?feed=rss2&post_type=news

the elements I am trying to read from this link are pubDate, title, description

but no results appear on the screen is there any solution for this??

Comment: Did you try with another feed ?

Answer (score 1):

[Your rss is not valid.](http://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.jopharma.com%2F%3Ffeed%3Drss2%26post_type%3Dnews)

[image]

You can try with this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/22869529).

If it works, your problem come from your feed.